# Trying to convert number to bigint in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone help me to fix this issue please?

I'm getting an error while trying to convert this to `BIGINT`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, '10472553255347451137')
```

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well, your number simply is to large for a `bigint`. A `bigint`'s maximum is 9223372036854775807, see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

And as 9223372036854775807 < 10472553255347451137, there's no way to convert 10472553255347451137 to a `bigint`.

And BTW, do not post images of error messages. Paste the text into the post's text.

Answer (score 0):

If you query for the length of the number, it's 20.  Therefore, you may use `Numeric(20, 0)` to store the value.

Length

```
SELECT len('10472553255347451137')
```

```
20
```

Select converted value

```
SELECT CONVERT(numeric(20, 0), '10472553255347451137')
```

```
10472553255347451137
```